# Postfix + Django: SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, postfix-mta

I am complete novice to Postfix, just set up default Postfix for Ubuntu, tested it through telnet and it sent mail ok, but when I try to send mail through django (host='localhost', port='25', user='', password=''), I just get

`SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.`

Here is my main.cf: https://gist.github.com/3348411

Could you please suggest, what I need to add to set up minimal working smtp just for sending email?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you don't really want to use AUTH.  In that case, user and password should be None, not the empty string.  If you look at the code base, Django [checks explicitly for None](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L21).  Since the default is None already, you can just leave off the username and password parameters.

HTH!

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works. I've looked at another server (Django 1.1) and there username/password was '', just did as there.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Django 1.1 did this a [little differently](https://github.com/django/django/blob/27358368879cc7d56756f12155393d3277fc52aa/django/core/mail.py#L113).  In that case, Django 1.1 would have defaulted to whatever was in settings, which was probably None.  It looks like that code has all changed fairly substantially since then. :-)