# Failing at sending mail from django

Tags: django, email, postfix-mta

I'm trying to send an "email" from a website in django.
I have completed the main code for doing so:

-)the view function 
-)the URLs mapping to make the function reachable from code
-)the sending form at a template

So my sending form would trigger the view function using the path specified in the URLS.

On my server, I have a "postfix" instance installed and tried.

I tried to edit changes in the settings.py and the views.py for about 2 days now but nothing worked.

The errors range between these two

1)

```
SMTPNotSupportedError at /website/email_send
```

when settings are

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mydomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25 //same for port 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'uname'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd!'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

2)

```
gaierror at /website/email_send
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

when settings are

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.mydomain.com' or 'smtp.mydomain.com'

EMAIL_PORT = 25 //same for port 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'uname'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd!'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I expect the email to be sent using a form in my django site run on a server using postfix

Comment: If postfix is running on the same machine, try supplying `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to `EMAIL_HOST`. If it is on another machine, then you'd need to set appropriate MX records in your DNS settings.

Comment: I changed it to "localhost" and the error message changed to ConnectionRefusedError at /website/email_send
[Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: problem is not on your code, it is the server.

Comment: @MohammedBaashar Is postfix running? If yes, is it running on port 25?

Comment: @xyres I kept it on the default since installation (that is port 25). Yes it is running and receiving mail

Comment: @Ken thought so. I revised the code million times

Comment: @MohammedBaashar Seems like postfix is not configured to accept connections from localhost. See if you can connect with it using the `telnet` command: `telnet localhost 25`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now fixed.
I found this question and used its answer:

[Postfix + Django: SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951292/postfix-django-smtpexception-smtp-auth-extension-not-supported-by-server)

I removed EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'uname' and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd!'

Then it worked without errors. The settings now are:
    ...
    EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    ...